# Multiple category bar plots

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset that looks similar to this:

```
Year Guild Habitat Count
2008 C     P       2
2008 F     P       12
2008 I     P       14
2008 C     S       1
2008 F     S       25
2008 I     S       12
2011 C     P       1
2011 F     P       14
2011 I     P       20
2011 C     S       1
2011 F     S       30
2011 I     S       12
```

I would Like to create a bar plot [like this one I've crudely drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ihAd.jpg) because I cannot get it to look like anything similar on R.

I have managed to make the right sort of graph for a single year, but even then I had to change the data so it looked like this:

[image]

```
Guild Habitat
C     P
C     P
F     P
F     P
F     P
...   ...
```

Which I did by hand. Clearly there is a better way to do this.
The actual data has more than 3 guilds and compares more than 2 years.

To sum up:

1)How do you plot bar plots with multiple categories?

2)How do you get R to read frequency counts from tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data frame, `dataset`, with the same structure as that in your question, the plot can be achieved using `ggplot2`. There are lots of tutorials and documentation for `ggplot2` on the Web, for example [this one](http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
dataset %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Guild, Count)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Habitat), position = "dodge") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

In English this says: "plot count versus guild as a column chart, fill column colour by habitat, place columns side by side (dodge) and place charts in their own container by year (facet)." With more years, you'd need to experiment with `facet_wrap` or maybe `facet_grid`.

Result: [image]